# TypeError forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to append array coming from response to some container by javascript forEach function. But getting an error of "response.cat_products.forEach is not a function". What is my wrong?

```php
    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'success',
        'cat_products' => $cat_products,
        'cat_count' => $cat_count
    ]);
```

```js
    if (response.status == true) {
        response.cat_products.forEach(filter); //filter is a function

    }
```

Comment: @berend I don't need elements of `myArray` for now. I am just trying to execute a function of `filter` for each row of `myArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a response is returned from Laravel controller like

```php
return response()->json([
    'status' => true,
    'message' => 'success',
    'cat_products' => $cat_products,
    'cat_count' => $cat_count
]);
```

Then the actual array is available on the javascript side under the response.data key.

Since you are doing loose comparison in the if statement it is being compared with response.status: 200 and not your supplied `"status" => true` in the json response

```js
if (response.status == true) {
    //response.data should contain the data sent as response from controller
    console.log(response.data); 
    
    //response.cat_products.forEach(filter); //filter is a function

    response.data.cat_products.forEach(filter);  //this should work

}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. You are true in that array is under data key but I have to write `response.cat_products.data.forEach(filter)`. This solved my problem